# Does Roslyn actually allow you to manipulate TreatWarningsAsErrors for a CSharp project?

Tags: c#, msbuild, compiler-warnings, roslyn

I'm trying to retrieve the setting TreatWarningsAsErrors, but I'm unable to find it for a project of my loaded solution.

What I'm trying to accomplish, is to get the setting from the project files, and set it to `true`, if it's not already that. Next, I want to let Roslyn do a compilation with the new setting, so I can check if this will break the project.

I've looked at various places, among others, the `Project.CompilationOptions`. Most options to a project build are there, except this one.

The [`CompilationOptions`](http://source.roslyn.io/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis/Compilation/CompilationOptions.cs) contains all the build settings, such as warning level, etc. But `TreatWarningsAsErrors` is not there. Am I looking at the wrong place?

The way I'm opening the solution is similar to the [`FormatSolution sample`](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/tree/master/src/Samples/CSharp/FormatSolution):

```
var solutionFile = @"C:\ties\src\playground\EnforceTreatAllWarningsAsErrors\EnforceTreatAllWarningsAsErrors.sln";

var workspace = MSBuildWorkspace.Create();
var solution = workspace.OpenSolutionAsync(solutionFile).Result;
var project = solution.Projects.Single();

// warning level is there
var warningLevel = project.CompilationOptions.WarningLevel;

// treat warnings as errors is not there... The following doesn't compile :(
bool treatWarningsAsErrors = project.CompilationOptions.TreatWarningsAsErrors;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for

```
compilationOptions.WithGeneralDiagnosticOption(ReportDiagnostic.Error)
```

[Source](http://source.roslyn.io/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Workspaces/LanguageServices/CSharpHostBuildDataFactory.cs,173)

Comment: Thanks! I don't know how I've missed that... Now, being able to change the option, I'm finding out that saving that is not supported :( I'm getting a [`NotSupportedException`](http://source.roslyn.io/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces/Workspace/Workspace.cs#909), when saving the solution file (`workspace.TryApplyChanges(...)`), like in the [`FormatSolution`](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/master/src/Samples/CSharp/FormatSolution/Program.cs) sample.

Comment: It looks like MSBuildWorkspace isn't very nice about this.  http://source.roslyn.io/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces.Desktop/Workspace/MSBuild/MSBuildWorkspace.cs,904  It sort of makes sense, especially because they might be in a conditional `<PropertyGroup>`.  You could edit the MSBuild XML directly, or file a feature request on GitHub.

Comment: Yes, indeed. That's what I'm going to do now. I was just hoping to leverage Roslyn to do that, since I'm already using it to test if the project is building, before and after ;)