# Exception thrown when adding new project into solution

Tags: c#, roslyn

I'm trying to programatically add new project into solution via Roslyn.

```
        var msWorkspace = MSBuildWorkspace.Create();

        var solution = msWorkspace.OpenSolutionAsync(Constants.pathToSolution).Result;

        var projectId = ProjectId.CreateNewId();
        var versionStamp = VersionStamp.Create();

        var info = ProjectInfo.Create(
                        id: projectId,
                        version: versionStamp,
                        name: "Redux",
                        assemblyName: "Redux.dll",
                        language: LanguageNames.CSharp);

        var newSolution = solution.AddProject(info);

        msWorkspace.TryApplyChanges(newSolution);
```

After this, the exception is thrown:

**"System.NotSupportedExcpetion: Adding projects is not suported."**

When I iterate over changed solution before trying to apply changes, the new project is present there. Adding new documents into projects works without any issues.

Is there a way to add new project into solution and save the changed solution?

Comment: Are you trying to save the changes to disk, or just save them in memory to the current Workspace?

Comment: I don't think it's possible. It looks to be similar to what [I asked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30458213/does-roslyn-actually-allow-you-to-manipulate-treatwarningsaserrors-for-a-csharp#comment49013335_30462947) about changes to things in the project, [which isn't possible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30458213/does-roslyn-actually-allow-you-to-manipulate-treatwarningsaserrors-for-a-csharp#comment49013430_30462947), as well, according to @SLaks.

Comment: @JoshVarty : I'm trying to save the changes to disk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Roslyn does not have any code that writes `.sln` files.
(you can see their solution reader [here](http://source.roslyn.io/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces.Desktop/Workspace/MSBuild/SolutionFile/SolutionFile.cs))

You can't do that.